# Mutli-Factor Authentication Sign-Up Redirection

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Azure AD B2C for my ASP.NET project. I want to use Multi-Factor authentication. Normally, after the sign-up, the user is redirected to the page to verify his phone number. I want to change this flow, I want to enable multi-factor if the user choose in a custom dropdown attribute 'Notifications' SMS, the other options are Email/No.

How can I redirect to this Multi-Factor page/Enable Multi-Factor depending on a value of a custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Well, fortunately, the Azure B2C is quite a flexible tool and does exactly what you're asking for. You're free to define custom policies, attributes and user flows (this one is in preview state though). For your case, if you're the one who manages the tenant, go to B2C instance and select 'User flows (preview)' blade. Create a User attribute beforehand. Configure the flow as necessary. Complete configuration by running the user flow. More on the issue can be found in quite exhausting [MS article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies).